# matching similar elements in between two lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, keyword-search

I'm new to python so apologies if its a silly question.

I have two lists
 `L1=['marvel','audi','mercedez','honda']` and

`L2=['marvel comics','bmw','mercedez benz','audi']`.

I want to extract matching elements which contains in `list L2` matched with `list L1`. So what I done :

```
for i in L1:
   for j in L2:
       if j in i:
          print (j)

  output is ['audi']
```

But, I also wants to return elements if its also consist any word match like `mercedez` in `mercedez benz` and `marvel` in `marvel comics`. so final output would be:

```
j=['audi','mercedez benz','marvel comics']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you really want here is the elements of `L2` that contain any elements in `L1`. So simply replace `if j in i` with `if i in j`:

```
for i in L1:
   for j in L2:
       if i in j:
          print (j)
```

This outputs:

```
marvel comics
audi
mercedez benz
```

Comment: Yes indeed. Good spotting of my typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use `regular expressions` then you can do:

```
import re
re.findall(".*|".join(L1),"\n".join(L2))

['marvel comics', 'mercedez benz', 'audi']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach  using `str.startswith`

**Ex:**

```
L1=['marvel','audi','mercedez','honda']  
L2=['marvel comics','bmw','mercedez benz','audi']
res = []
for i in L2:
    for j in L1:
        if i.startswith(j):
            res.append(i)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['marvel comics', 'mercedez benz', 'audi']
```

Using `in`

**Ex:**

```
res = []
for i in L2:
    for j in L1:
        if j in i:
            res.append(i)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

a performant approach would be to build a "flat" dictionary with each word as key and the relevant group of words as value.

```
L2=['marvel comics','bmw','mercedes benz','audi']    
match_dict = {k:v for v in L2 for k in v.split()}
```

which is:

```
{'audi': 'audi',
 'benz': 'mercedes benz',
 'bmw': 'bmw',
 'comics': 'marvel comics',
 'marvel': 'marvel comics',
 'mercedes': 'mercedes benz'}
```

now scan the first list and issue element if in dictionary:

```
L1=['marvel','audi','mercedes','honda']
result = [match_dict[x] for x in L1 if x in match_dict]
```

result:

```
['marvel comics', 'audi', 'mercedes benz']
```

once the dictionary is built, you can scan large lists with high performance (`O(1)` lookup)

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
[j for i in L1 for j in L2 if (j.startswith(i))]

['marvel comics', 'audi', 'mercedez benz']
```