# matching similar elements between list and list in pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493185/matching-similar-elements-in-between-two-lists). and this one its modified form so I post it as new question. I have a list as `L2=['marvel comics','bmw','mercedez benz','audi']`.

I have a pandas dataframe with column name `words_col` consists list of elements in each cell and wants to match columns lists with `list L2` and put it in new columns `match_words`.
It should return elements if its also consist any word match like `mercedez` in `mercedez benz` and `marvel` in `marvel comics`. So, final output would be.

```
words_col                                   match_words
['marvel','car', 'entertainment','audi']    ['marvel comics','audi']
['audi','usa','benz']                       ['audi']
['movies','imdb','chrome','mercedez']       ['mercedez benz']     
......
......
```

What I have tried:

```
res = []
for i in df['words_col']:
    for a in i:
       for j in L2:
         if a in j:
            print (j)
```

It gives all words together. How I can add it into pandas column as match keywords should be corresponding to each cell of `words_col`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'words_col': [['marvel','car', 'entertainment','audi'],
                                 ['audi','usa'],
                                 ['movies','imdb','chrome','mercedez']]})

words = ['marvel comics','bmw','mercedez benz','audi']

df['match_words'] = df['words_col'].apply(lambda terms: [word for word in words if any(term in word for term in terms)])

df
#                            words_col            match_words
#0  [marvel, car, entertainment, audi]  [marvel comics, audi]
#1                         [audi, usa]                 [audi]
#2    [movies, imdb, chrome, mercedez]        [mercedez benz]
```

**EDIT**

```
df['match_words'] = df['words_col'].apply(lambda terms: [word for word in words if any(word.startswith(term) for term in terms)])
```

This will look if the `word` begins with `word` as per your latest comment.

Comment: Thankyou so much. Excellent :)

Comment: One more thing, I want matching based on first word only. i.e it should pick 'mercedez benz' if there is 'mercedez' in pandas list. If there is 'benz' in pandas list then I dont't want to include 'mercedez benz'

Comment: @Mavrick Edited answer.